# pywinauto view list items that aren't visible on screen

Tags: python, pywinauto, zoom-sdk

I'm trying to get a list of participants in my zoom meeting through pywinauto.
So far I've got it got it to connect to the zoom meeting window, open up the participants tab and store the names that are visible in a list and return it.

```
# Locates the participants list window
    participants_list_box = zoom_meeting.Participants.child_window(title="participant list, use arrow key to navigate, and press tab for more options", control_type="List").wrapper_object()
    
    attendees = []
    # Looping through each item in the list box
    for child in participants_list_box.children():
        # Getting the text for each item in the list
        window_text = child.window_text()

        """ Seperating the other parts and taking the name part 
        only and appending it to the list because the window_text 
        is a single string.
        
        Example: ("Some Name Here, (Me), Computer audio muted, Video off")""" 

        attendee_name = window_text.split(",")[0]
        attendees.append(attendee_name)
```

I'm trying to find out how to either scroll down through the participants list with pywinauto and store each item or get all the ListItems all at once without them having to be visible.

Comment: I have found a potential solution [Scrolling](https://pastebin.com/FgHdsgje) from another stackoverflow post. Just have to change the wheel_dist value to a negative number.

Comment: These items may be so called "virtualized items". Some attempts to use VirtualizedItem pattern are here: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/985#issuecomment-699473112 Not sure it will work for you. Maybe it's not suitable for enumerating each item. It's useful if you already know the name so it scrolls down to correct item automatically.